# How can I click on the canvas?

Tags: testing, canvas, click, cypress

I need some help with clicking on the seat on the canvas.  I use the coordinate to get x,y.  It seems I get the right location but when I did run it I could not click on the seat and go to the next step.

```
cy.get('#chart-canvas').then($canvas => {
    cy.wrap($canvas)
    .scrollIntoView()
    .click(180,270,{force: true})  //F1 Seat  
})
```

[image]

I grab the `//canvas[@id='chart-canvas']`

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking or performing any of the click events(mousedown, mouseup, click, etc.) try moving the mouse.

I had the exact same problem. All clicks were successful and at the right coordinates. It just would not work.

Your code would look like this:

```js
// Move mouse to some random position
cy.get('#chart-canvas').trigger('mousemove', 100, 100);

// Click
cy.get('#chart-canvas').click(180, 270, { force: true });
```

Tested this on multiple different canvas projects.

Comment: I think that Cypress mouse movements are too fast for the Canvas. So adding a few random mouse movements should allow the Canvas to "register" the positions and perform normally.